# VB6 + crystal Report 9 null value

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, report

im working on project which require crystal report 9 and vb6.

i created a crystal report page an selected all columns i want .

then in form user select the data by this code

```
If frmRepTabaee1.Check1.Value = 1 And frmRepTabaee1.chbTamin.Value = 1 Then
     If frmRepTabaee1.txtTabai.Text = 1 Then
       sqlStr = "select pcode,name,lastname,TTaminDarman1,y,mon from tbllisthogh" & frmRepTabaee1.txty & "" & frmRepTabaee1.txtmon & " where typepar= 'ÍÞæÞ'  and idvoras = '0'  order by convert(int,pcode )"

       ElseIf frmRepTabaee1.txtTabai.Text = 2 Then
            sqlStr = "select pcode,name,lastname,TTaminDarman2,y,mon from tbllisthogh" & frmRepTabaee1.txty & "" & frmRepTabaee1.txtmon & " where typepar= 'ÍÞæÞ'  and idvoras = '0'  order by convert(int,pcode )"

       ElseIf frmRepTabaee1.txtTabai.Text = 3 Then
       sqlStr = "select pcode,name,lastname,TTaminDarman3,y,mon from tbllisthogh" & frmRepTabaee1.txty & "" & frmRepTabaee1.txtmon & " where typepar= 'ÍÞæÞ'  and idvoras = '0'  order by convert(int,pcode )"

       ElseIf frmRepTabaee1.txtTabai.Text = 4 Then
       sqlStr = "select pcode,name,lastname,TTaminDarman4,y,mon from tbllisthogh" & frmRepTabaee1.txty & "" & frmRepTabaee1.txtmon & " where typepar= 'ÍÞæÞ'  and idvoras = '0'  order by convert(int,pcode )"

       ElseIf frmRepTabaee1.txtTabai.Text = 5 Then
       sqlStr = "select pcode,name,lastname,TTaminDarman5,y,mon from tbllisthogh" & frmRepTabaee1.txty & "" & frmRepTabaee1.txtmon & " where typepar= 'ÍÞæÞ'  and idvoras = '0'  order by convert(int,pcode )"
              ElseIf frmRepTabaee1.txtTabai.Text = 6 Then
       sqlStr = "select pcode,name,lastname,TTaminDarman6,y,mon from tbllisthogh" & frmRepTabaee1.txty & "" & frmRepTabaee1.txtmon & " where typepar= 'ÍÞæÞ'  and idvoras = '0'  order by convert(int,pcode )"

    End If
End If
```

Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass

```
rs.Open sqlStr, cn


Report.Database.SetDataSource rs, , 1

'--------------------------------
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'''''''''''''''''''''
'-------------------
CRViewer91.Refresh
'-------------------

CRViewer91.ReportSource = Report
CRViewer91.ViewReport
Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
'End If
End Sub
```

Problem :

when sql query use diffrent columns to be select and that cuse the null problem in crystal report 9 , how can i set default value for null ?

in vb6& crystal report 9

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have version 9, but somewhere in Crystal Reports general settings for the report options you should have checkboxes for **Convert Database NULL Values to Default** and **Convert Other NULL Values to Default**. Checking those should eliminate your errors.[image]

Comment: there isnt any option like this in CR9

Comment: @madman Versions 8, and 2008 have it so it must exist in version 9 also. Try looking at File - Report Options.